# Javascript problems with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I'm having rows,for which i need to append controls dynamically.
code for it is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddRowContent()
{
    //Here trRow is a id of row for which I need to append the data.
    var d=document.getElementById("trRow");
    d.innerHTML="<td>Aliases</td>";     
}
</script>
```

Code is working fine with other browsers,
but it's not working properly with Internet Explorer.
Please Let me know solution or better way to do this.

Comment: Before asking more questions and expecting people to help you out – please review your previous ones and perhaps accept some of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

In IE, innerHTML on tr elements is readOnly.

***Solution:***

```
var d=document.getElementById("trRow");
var td = document.createElement('td');
td.innerHTML = "Aliases";
d.appendChild(td);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `innerHTML` property is **readonly** for `<tr>` element in IE, as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx) described:

> The innerHTML property is read-only on the col, colGroup, frameSet, html, head, style, table, tBody, tFoot, tHead, title, and tr objects.
>
> You can change the value of the title element using the document.title property.
>
> To change the contents of the table, tFoot, tHead, and tr elements, use the table object model described in [Building Tables Dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms532998(v=vs.85).aspx). However, to change the content of a particular cell, you can use innerHTML.

So to manipulate your table, try read [Building Tables Dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms532998(v=vs.85).aspx) and find a solution, for your simple case, use DOM API could be a compatible solution:

```
var td = document.createElement('td');
td.innerHTML = 'Aliases';
// Remove all existing <td> element
while (d.firstChild) {
    d.removeChild(d.firstChild);
}
d.appendChild(td);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstRow=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0];
var x=firstRow.insertCell(-1);
x.innerHTML="New cell"
```